# data environment en 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb

he estado programando en VB6 con data environment para acceder a los datos, ahora me estoy mudando a vb.net con Visual Studio 2010 y quiero agregar ese componente, he leído y en varios lugares me dicen que para el vb.net no existe ese componente, la pregunta es? que componente similar me aconsejan ocupar en caso de que data environment no exista para vb.net?

Comment: En el mundo de .NET, vendría bien aprender en cuanto a ADO.NET, y tal vez Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Environment es un tecnologia antigua, eso no existe en la plataforma .NET, para extraer datos de un repositorio de datos lo haces a traves de ADO.NET y esos datos los devueleve en un DataTable que es lo que puedes usar para poder tus consultas, te dejo un ejemplo para poder llenar un reporte con ADO.NET
[enlace](https://vbcodigopocketpc.blogspot.com/search?q=crystal%20report) es algo simple aunque hay otras formas pero en lo que te acostumbras a una nueva tecnologia